# Django How to check id of ForeignKey?

Tags: django

I have models.py like this. which api_key in table UserKey is ForeignKey to api_key in table DeviceKey.

```
class DeviceKey(models.Model):
    
    api_key=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.api_key
   

class UserKey(models.Model):
    api_key=models.ForeignKey(DeviceKey,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

The data in table DeviceKey and Userkey show like this code.

```
Table DeviceKey
id  api_key
1    abc1
2    abc2

Table Userkey
id  api_key_id
1     1
```

I want to check if api_key exists in table Userkey but I can't search with text beacause table UserKey keep api_key as id. So, I have to get id from table DeviceKey like this code

```
key="abc2"
if UserKey.objects.filter(username=username,api_key_id=DeviceKey.objects.get(api_key=key).values_list('id')).exists():
```

It show error like this.

`'DeviceKey' object has no attribute 'values_list'`

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you if your api_key in Device_key is 'abc1'

```
   UserKey.objects.filter(api_key__api_key='abc1').exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

While using foreign key, try to make use of related_name property in the table that is having (many relationship).

```
class DeviceKey(models.Model):

    api_key=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.api_key


class UserKey(models.Model):
    api_key=models.ForeignKey(DeviceKey,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_key')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

If you want to get the records of 'api_key' of model 'DeviceKey' in realtionship with 'UserKey' model rows. You can make use of 'realted_name' as below

```
api_key_obj = DeviceKey.objects.get(api_key='api_key_value')
```

This gives list of all the rows of 'UserKey' that are in relationship with the 'api_key_obj'.
api_key_obj.user_key

Returns true or false depending on the existence of relationship between 'DeviceKey' and 'UserKey' for 'api_key_obj'.

```
api_key_obj.user_key.exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You can also try this

UserKey.objects.filter(api_key__api_key='test').exists()